# No advantage from SSD boot drive for 24/7 server?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, boot, kernel, ssd

Since my OS and applications are loaded into memory upon boot, isn't there no advantage from having my OS on an SSD boot drive for a server that is kept up 24/7? I know there are several assumptions that depend on how I use that server, so for the purpose of this question, let's assume:

1. No I/O tasks on my applications.
2. No applications on disk that need to be loaded after boot.
3. No need for fast reboot after a crash.

Basically, I want to know if there is some random I/O carried out by kernel processes that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if there is some random I/O carried out by kernel
>   processes that I'm unaware of?

Well we don't know what you're aware of nor do you actually mention an operating system, but if we assume you mean Linux then there's unlikely to be anything purely-OS-based that would significantly benefit from the improved random IO capacity of an SSD over a HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. No advantage.

Well, not totally.

SSD are very reliable when not written too often - they are RELIABLE when written to, but without a lot of writes they are terrific, especially in case of physical abuse.

BUt for a server - no. I moved all high performance stuff to SSD Cached raid controllers and now use the retired Velociraptors for booting. No sense in spending hugh money for a bood ssd.

THAT SAID: SSD are also cheap if you need only a SMALL boot volume. 32gb hard discs sort of do not exist.

Comment: Good point on the costs - I nearly forgot. SSD idle vs HDD idle power consumption in a 24/7 application could probably breakeven for its initial cost within 1-3 years.